# mysql, how to create table and automatically track users who add or delete rows/tables

Tags: mysql, perl

I would like some kind of revision control history for my sql database.

I would like this table to keep updating with a record of who, deleted what, etc, when.

I am connecting to MySQL using Perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Approach 1: Create a separate "audit" table and use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to populate the info.

Here's a brief guide for MySQL (and Postrges): http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=7252

Approach 2: Populate the audit info from your Perl database access code. Ideally, as part of the same transaction. There's no significant win over the first approach and many downsides (you don't catch changes made OUTSIDE of your code, for one)

Comment: One downside I can see of using triggers over the application method is human error.If you create a new table and forget to create the appropriate triggers, you lose the audit tracking. The application level is defaulted to track everything (done through the application) with the ability to turn it off for specific cases. Your point about not tracking anything done outside of the application is valid for +1

Comment: @DTest - Yikes! It's a valid technical consideration. BUT... if someone faces this problem, they got a LOT bigger issues than losing audit on one table. It means they have no good controls on DDL (including change management and reviews)! Because proper control can easily include "Did you create audit infrastructure for new table" bullet - ideally enforced by meta data check script.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: I faced this situation in the past, but in PHP. Concepts are for PHP but could be applied to perl with some thought.

I played with the idea of adding triggers to each table `AFTER INSERT`, `AFTER UPDATE`, `AFTER DELETE`
to accomplish the same thing. The problem with this was:

- the trigger didn't know the 'admin' user, just the db user (`CURRENT_USER`)
- Biggest issue was that it wasn't feasible to add these triggers to all my tables (I suppose I could have written a script to add the triggers).
- Maintainability of the triggers. If you change how things are tracked, you'd have to update all triggers. I suppose having the trigger call a stored procedure would mostly fix that issue.

Either way, for my situation, I found the best course of action was in the application layer (not DB layer):

- create a DB abstraction layer if you haven't already (Class that handles all the interaction with the database).
- create function for each action (insert, update, delete).
- in each of these functions, after a successful query call, add another query that would insert the relevant information to your tracking table

If done properly, any action you perform to update any table will be tracked. I had to add some overrides for specific tables to not track (what's the point of tracking inserts on the 'track_table' table, for instance). Here's an example table tracking schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `track_table` (
  `id` int(16) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userID` smallint(16) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tableName` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tupleID` int(16) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_insert` datetime NOT NULL,
  `action` char(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userID` (`userID`),
  KEY `tableID` (`tableName`,`tupleID`,`date_insert`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: @DTest - why couldn't you get the user for the trigger via `USER` instead of `CURRENT_USER`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-activity-auditing.html

Comment: @DVK it's still based on the connected user. In my application (which might nto be true for OP) I use one connection, so logging the mysql user tells me nothing.

Comment: @DTest - can't you provide an optional "App user" value in a variable that the trigger can read (and default to `USER()` if not set)? Something like setting app context in Sybase/Oracle.

Comment: @DVK hadn't thought of doing it that way at the time. It would work.

Comment: @DTest - enjoy. Life's better when you can steal ideas from other spheres of interest (in this case Sybase :)